# Android - cant get phone number of some contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts, phone-number, contactscontract

I'm having a problem with extracting phone numbers of some people in my contact list.

First I show all the contacts in a listview:

```
String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
    };

mCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            projection, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] {mContactId}, null);
```

When clicking on an item, this is how I fetch the contact_id:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Cursor currentCursor = mContactsAdapter.getCursor();

    if (currentCursor != null) {
        notifyOnContactSelectedListeners(String.valueOf(id));
    }
}
```

Then I create a new fragment, and while loading it I query for the contact's phone & display name:

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        String firstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
    }
```

So for some people that has a phone, I get the phone number this way and that's ok.
But for some people I can't get the phone number this way - but they do have phone number in the default's phone contacts book.

What went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar difficulty. I discovered that the numbers that I was unable to receive had all been imported from my linked Facebook account. You will be able to detect that the contact exists, and indeed that they have a phone number. However, when you try to retrieve said number with a SQL query the result returned will be `null`.

It transpired that Facebook restrict access to their contacts for security reasons. I am yet to find another provider (e.g. LinkedIn, Google) which hides phone numbers.

Further reading: [Cannot find Facebook contacts in RawContacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038290/cannot-find-facebook-contacts-in-rawcontacts)

Comment: maybe it becomes a facebook account after you merge or link the accounts ?

Answer (score 0):

try this may it useful for you

public class  Contact extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

```
private static final int PICK_CONTACT = 0;
Cursor c;
Cursor cursor,phones,emails,address;
String id,phoneNo,name;
String[] from;
int[] to;
ListView lv;
Cursor cur,pCur;
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.contact);
  lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contactlist);
  displayContacts();
  lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list1)); 
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

private void displayContacts() {

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
   cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
             name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                  pCur = cr.query(
                         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                         null, 
                         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
                         new String[]{id}, null);
                 while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                     phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                 // setContact(name,phoneNo);
                     System.out.println("name"+name+"ph no"+phoneNo);
                     list1.add(name+"\n"+phoneNo);
            //       Toast.makeText(this, "Name: " + name + ", Phone No: " + phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                 } 

            pCur.close();
          }
        }
    }




}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String s = lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();

    Log.i("my msg", s.substring(0, s.indexOf("\n")));

    Toast.makeText(this, s.substring(s.indexOf("\n")+1,s.length() ),1 ).show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I received `null` in some contacts.

I verified my code to find out that when querying phone numbers I was using `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER` then I changed to `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER` that according to android [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone#NUMBER) it says.

> The phone number as the user entered it.

and the code worked well.

Comment: Your before and after appear exactly the same?

Comment: Thank you @Bink, I had a hard time finding the right value, lucky I copied over the description from the documentation.