# How to get all contacts with number? What I'm doing wrong?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

Hi actually I'm doing this to get all contacts that has number:

```
String[] projecao = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
        String selecao = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = ? ";
        Cursor contatos = contexto.getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projecao, selecao,
                new String[] { "1" }, null);
```

And to get all number of each contact:

```
while (contatos.moveToNext()){
    Cursor numbers = contexto
                    .getContentResolver()
                    .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER },
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                    + " = ?",
                            new String[] { contatos.getString(contatos
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)) },
                            null);
    numbers.moveToFirst();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                do {
                    sb.append(numbers.getString(numbers
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))
                            + ", ");
                } while (numbers.moveToNext());
}
```

But I can't pick number that come from facebook.

I receive that error: index 0 request. This error is because the cursor numbers did not match any number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you specifically trying to get phone numbers from Facebook contacts?

The FaceBook content provider is restricted. It will not let you retrieve phone numbers.

Please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026173/android-cant-get-phone-number-of-some-contacts) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038290/cannot-find-facebook-contacts-in-rawcontacts) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506571/how-to-get-a-contacts-facebook-id-or-url-from-native-contacts-content-resolve).

Comment: Not specifically, I want all of agenda.

Comment: @weldsonandrade I'm pretty sure this means that you cannot search Facebook contacts by their phone number either since you can't read any of that data in the content provider.